# Extension of Du-Bois-Raymond lemma to Vector Fields on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

*Edit: Reviving this thread because I still could not prove or find a proof of this. A sketch of a proof attempt can be found in the previous edit of this post.*

I am trying to show the following extension of the Du Bois Raymond lemma:

> Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian Manifold and  $\omega: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be a $W^{1,2}$ curve on M. Consider a tangential $L^2$ vector field along $\omega$ denoted by $v \in L^2(\omega^*TM)$.
>
> If $$\int_{0}^{1} \langle v, \frac{Du}{\partial t} \rangle \text{ dt} = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{for all } u \in W ^{1,2}(\omega^*TM) \text{ with } u(0)=u(1)=0$$
>
> Then
>
> $$v \in W^{1,2}(\omega^*TM)\ \ \text{ with   }\ \  \frac{Dv}{\partial t} = 0 \ \ a.e.$$
>
> where $\frac{Du}{\partial t}$ denotes the covariant derivative of $u$ along the curve $\omega$.

For my purposes it would be sufficient to show this for the simplified case where $M = S^2$ and the covariant derivative becomes the projection onto the respective tangent space, i.e., $\frac{Du}{\partial t} = u' - \langle u', \omega \rangle \omega$.

Kind regards.

Comment: It seems to me that the regular du Bois-Reymond lemma is *not* applicable, as you have the equality only for vector fields $u$ which are tangent to the sphere. I guess you would need this equality to hold for every vector field $u$ in order to use the du Bois-Reymond lemma. This makes sense, as you noted yourself, as the vector field $v$ usually cannot be constant as a function to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval That is indeed correct and a good find. It also only makes sense since I am expecting $v$ to only be constant along $\omega$ as well so I only have an assumptions made for the vector fields along $\omega$. At least the „extension“ seems intuitive. I’m going to edit my OP with your input, thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with a proof of the original du Bois-Reymond lemma? I'm guessing the argument you are looking for is an imitation of the one used in the original proof. The key ingredient is that the covariant derivative respects the Riemannian metric on the surface. In other words, you can use the Leibniz rule.

Comment: The original proof uses mollifications of the test function which are again test functions in the sense that they stay compactly supported. This is crucial since the function $v$ we‘re looking at is not differentiable and we can roll the mollification onto $v$ which in turn is differentiable. The same would be needed here, since we don’t know if $v$ is covariantly differentiable along $/omega$ at all: Is there a possibility for a mollification $u_/varepsilon$ such that the $u_/varepsilon$ stays a vector field along the curve $\omega$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval If there was, I think Leibniz rule and the Fundamental Lemma would work.

Comment: I will start by saying that I have never done this kind of work, so I am no expert. However, it seems to me very natural to proceed as follows. Let $e_1,e_2$ be a (parallel, orthonormal) frame of $\omega^*TM$. Then any section $v$ is just a linear combination of the elements of the frame; $v=v^1e_1+v^2e_2,$ where $v^1,v^2$ are functions on the interval. Furthermore, as the frame is *smooth*, a section $v$ is of regularity $W^{k,p}$ if and only if both corresponding functions are. Now just replace the section $v$ by the $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued function $(v^1,v^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Amitai Yuval's comment...

**Fact.** A function $g\in L^2((0,1),\mathbb R)$ that satisfies $\int gf=0$ for all compactly supported smooth $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R,$ must satisfy $g\equiv 0$ a.e.

See for example Haim Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, [Corollary 4.24](https://books.google.co.uk/booksid=1bFCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA102&vq=corollary%204.24&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&lr&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false).

More generally, for a finite dimensional inner product space $V,$ a function $g\in L^2((0,1),V)$ satisfying $\int \langle g,f\rangle=0$ for all $f\in C^\infty_c((0,1),V)$ must be zero a.e. - just pick a basis and apply the Fact to each component. So a function $g\in L^2((0,1),T_{\omega(0)}M)$ that satisfies $\int \langle g,f\rangle=0$ for all compactly supported $f\in C^\infty_c((0,1),T_{\omega(0)}M)$ must satisfy $g\equiv 0$ a.e.

Parallel transport gives an isometry of the fiber at $t$ to the fibre at $0,$ in symbols $T_{\omega(t)}M\cong T_{\omega(0)}M,$ and these give a smooth isometric trivialization $\omega^*TM\cong [0,1]\times T_{\omega(0)}M.$ So any function $g\in L^2(\omega^*TM)$ that satisfies $\int \langle g,f\rangle=0,$ for all $g\in C^\infty(\omega^*TM)$ supported on a compact subset of $(0,1),$ must satisfy $g\equiv 0$ a.e.

---

Bringing this back to the original problem, we are given $v\in W^{1,2}(\omega^*TM)$ such that

$$\int_0^1 \langle v,\frac{Du}{\partial t}\rangle =0$$

for all $u\in C^\infty(\omega^*TM)$ supported on a compact subset of $(0,1).$ By one definition of the weak derivative $Dv/\partial t,$

$$\int_0^1 \langle \frac{Dv}{\partial t},u\rangle=-\int_0^1 \langle v,\frac{Du}{\partial t}\rangle\tag{*}$$
for such $u,$ but we've just said this is zero. So $Dv/\partial t=0$ a.e.

I'm assuming (*), but you might be working with a different definition where this isn't immediate. (*) is the special case of the definition $\int_0^1 \langle \nabla v,u\rangle=-\int_0^1 \langle v,\nabla u\rangle$ for weak derivatives on vector bundles with connection $\nabla$ (the covariant derivative along a curve is the covariant derivative defined by the pullback connection, along the standard vector field $d/dt$).